# Is there a minhag to the order of eating fish & meat during Shabbat meals?

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah

I've seen many people eat fish in addition to eating meat during a Shabbat meal. (See [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8342/5275) for the origin of the fish minhag.)

Almost every place I have attended as a guest (both Ashkenazim and Sefardim) tend to eat the fish before the meat.

Is there any minhag or halacha that mentions this as being the preferred order?

Comment: Appetizers come before the main course ;)

Comment: Possibly bc meat is more likely to get stuck in your teeth?

Comment: @robev "appetizer" is a relative term when it comes to most Shabbat meals. The same fried flounder that I eat on Wednesday as a main course becomes an "appetizer" only because I eat a bigger meal on Shabbat. I've seen people have stuffed cabbage as appetizer followed by bronzini for main course.